# How to display Google App Contacts in a separate iChat list?

Tags: google-apps, ichat

I have a few accounts in iChat:

- GMail
- AIM
- Google Apps (a custom domain)

Both GMail and Google Apps put all my contacts in the 'Buddies' list. Can I rename my Gmail list to "GMail Contacts' or something else so that both accounts dont get merged?

Comment: I would be nice if you could format this question a little cleaner, especially that "GMail AIM Google Apps" line. Click the yellow backgrounded '?' icon for details.

Comment: is this on OS X or iOS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually just tried this and iChat does it automatically. As you can see I have a different window for each account, and I think you can actually set the window's title by setting the account description under `Settings`->`Accounts`. As you can see I even have different groups for each account.  [image: screenshot]

Although I usually have them unified using Chax's feature `Use All Contacts window as primary contact list`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, and Yes.  Just add a new group, and then drag your Google App contacts to the newly named group.  It's really that easy. You can right click on any group name, and select *rename*.

You can also do the same with [Adium](http://adium.im/about/)

[image]

Comment: Groups != List Segmentation. Putting all your buddies on one account into a group = organization hell, and will really start to suck down the road. Especially if (god forbid) you move onto a client other than iChat.